# Clear property-(public) List without clearing the private List

Tags: c#, list, private, encapsulation

I'm new to C# (first post) and currently working on a problem regarding "encapsulation".
Basically I have two classes like this (simplified):

```
class Myclass
    {

        private List<X> _list;
        public List<X> list
        {
            get
            {
                return _list;
            }
        }
        ...
        public Myclass (List<X> input)
        {
          _list = new List <X>(input);
        }
        ...
     }

class Testclass
    {
      List<X> inputList = new List<X>() {"bla", "bla"};
      Myclass myclass = new Myclass(inputlist);

      myclass.list.Clear();
      List<X> newL = myclass.list;
    }
```

I'm not supposed to change anything with the second class "Testclass".

And this is my problem:
myclass.list.Clear() clears the public list AND the private list. But I only want it to clear the public list or do nothing at all because in the end I need the list newL to be filled with the items out of the private list (public list via get-accessor).

Since I'm supposed to solve the problem without touching the second class I have no idea what to do.
I've been told that the public list is called a property, is this right? If so, what is the public list called?

Like I said, I'm pretty bad/new in programming in general (19 y/o) so beginner-friendly answers would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public List<X> list
{
    get
    {
        return new List<X>(_list);
    }
}
```

This will return a *copy* of the list every time. So from the outside, the caller never gets access to the *real* list on the inside. He can do with the copy whatever he wants, clear, add, remove. It will not change the private list.

Please note that in real production code you would instead change the property to not return a list, but something that simply does not *have* the option to change it (like an `IEnumerable<T>`). Giving somebody a *List* and then ignoring whatever he does with it is very unintuitive for the caller and not exactly good programming.

Comment: Perfect answer as far as I understand it. Totally makes sense. Thank you very much, I will test it in a second :) <3

Comment: You could also use `return _list.ToList()` instead of the new constructor (I don't know which one is the most efficient)

Comment: @fharreau As `.ToList()` does [exactly the same](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L835) as my line of code, using the list constructor could be seen as marginally more efficient (saving a null-check). As that's not the level of efficiency one should care about, use whatever enhances readability the most.

Comment: Tested it and it works! Thanks for the help :) Happy af right now!

Comment: This answer is correct, but cloning (or copying) the list is expensive, especially if it is done each time the property is accessed. If the property is accessed way more often then the value of the field changes, could it be better to work with a `ReadOnlyCollection`?

Comment: @lukegv That's the point of the whole second paragraph. Personally, I'd return an `IEnumerable<T>` as a `return _list.Select(x => x);` but everybody has their own preference. I hate the .NET ReadOnlyXXX implementations, because they implement the real thing (for example `ICollection`) only to throw an exception later. That's crappy. If something is not meant to be manipulated, it should not provide methods for doing so.

Comment: @lukegv The ReadOnlyCollection does not provide a Clear method. So the test method won't compile.

Comment: @fharreau I'm afraid it *does*. It just throws an `NotSupportedException` when you actually call it :(

Comment: @nvoigt `ReadOnlyCollection<Object> test = [..]; test.Clear();` does not compile on my computer (Visual Studio 2015 Pro). I always wonder why, while ReadOnlyCollection extends Collection that does provide the Clear methods ...

Comment: @fharreau I only checked MSDN. I guess it's implemented explicitely.

Answer (score 1):

When the list is accessed via your property, it is the instance of the list, which is stored in your (backing-) field, so both lists are the same object. This is the reason why your `Clear` is called on the field. To deliver the list in a readonly way, you have two possibilities:

- You can clone the list: This way, the returned list is not the same object, but has the same elements like the original list. Example: `return _list.ToList();` or `return new List(_list);`
- You can use a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`. This is, like the name indicates, readonly, so noone can add or remove items.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It works! <3 The answer is similar to the one by nvoigt. Still thanks a lot!